# Reading, converting, and evaluating Infix to Postfix using Stacks

Tags: c, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to read infix expressions from a text file and then convert them to postfix and evaluate them and everything works until I reach the first while loop. The expression is converted but I stay stuck in the loop before evaluation happens. Does anyone know why? I'm sure it is something small that I am missing.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define RogueValue -99

typedef struct Stack {
       int top;
       char ST[50];
  }Stack;

Stack S;

int convertToPostfix(char infx[], char pofx[]);
char push(char ch);
char pop();
int isEmpty();
int precedence(char ch);
void printPostfix(char pofx[], int n);
int evaluate(char infx[], int size);

int main(void) { 

    FILE * f = fopen("2542.txt", "r"); //opening the input file
    char infx[50], pofx[50];

    S.top = -1;

    fscanf(f, "%s", infx);

    while(strcmp(infx,"\n")!= 0)  //?????????
    {
           convertToPostfix(infx, pofx);


           printf("Infix Expression: %s\n", infx); 

           printf("\nPostfix Expression: %s\n\n\n",pofx);
    }

    fclose(f); 


}



int convertToPostfix(char infx[], char pofx[]){

    char ch;

    int  i= 0, k = 0;



    while((ch = infx[i++]) != '\0') {  

         if( ch == '(')

             push(ch);



        else if(ch >='0' && ch <= '9')

             pofx[k++]=ch;



        else if( ch == ')') {

                 while( S.ST[S.top] != '(')

                    pofx[k++]=pop();             

                    ch = pop();

        }       

        else {     

            while( precedence(S.ST[S.top]) >= precedence(ch) )

                  pofx[k++]=pop();

                    push(ch);

        }

    }

    while( S.ST[S.top] != -1)     /* Pop from stack till empty */

        pofx[k++]=pop();

        return k;

} 

char push(char ch) {
      if (S.top == 50 - 1){

               printf("Stack overflow\n");

               return 1;

            }

    S.ST[++S.top] = ch;

}


char pop() { 
     if (isEmpty(S))

          return RogueValue;             

    char popped = S.ST[S.top];

     --(S.top);

           return popped;

}



int isEmpty(){

    return(S.top == -1);

}



int precedence(char ch){

    if ( ch == '(') return 1;

    if ( ch == '+' || ch == '-') return 2;
    if ( ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '%') return 3;


    if ( ch == '^') return 4;
    if ( ch == 'f') return 5;



}



int evaluate (char pofx[], int size){

    int i, a , b, c, n;

    Stack temp;



    S.top = -1; //init Stack



    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){

          if( pofx[i] <= '9' && pofx[i] >= '0')

                push (pofx[i] - '0');



          else {

              b = pop();

              a = pop();



              if (pofx[i] == '+')
                      c = a + b;



              else if (pofx[i] == '-')

                      c = a - b;

              else if (pofx[i] == '*')

                      c = a * b;

              else if (pofx[i] == '/')

                      c = a / b;

              else if (pofx[i] == '%')

                      c = a % b;

              else if (pofx[i] == '^'){

                   c = 1.0;

                   for(n = 1; n <= b; n++)

                         c = c*a;

              }

              else if (pofx[i] == 'f'){
                   for(n = pofx[i]; n > 0; n--)

                          c = c*n;

              }

              push(c);

         }

    }

    return pop();

}
```

and here are the input values:

2 + 4 * 8 / 2
  ( 100 + 200 )  / 3

and here is the output I am getting right now:

```
Infix Expression: 2+4*8/2

Postfix Expression: 248*2/+


Infix Expression: 2+4*8/2

Postfix Expression: 248*2/+


Infix Expression: 2+4*8/2

Postfix Expression: 248*2/+


Infix Expression: 2+4*8/2
```

.........

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `strcmp(infx,"\n")!= 0` never become false.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what should I change it then to make it eventually become false?

Comment: First, `%s` of `fscanf` does not include line breaks. In this format it is necessary to decide the input word to be terminated. E.g `strcmp(infx, "end")!= 0`. And you need to have the input at the end of the loop. E.g `printf("\nPostfix Expression: %s\n\n\n",pofx);` --> `printf("\nPostfix Expression: %s\n\n\n",pofx); fscanf(f, "%s", infx);`. However, I think that it is better to make sure that the input from the file failed rather than it. E.g `while(strcmp(infx,"\n")!= 0)` --> `while(fscanf(f, "%49s", infx)==1)`

Comment: I will try these things. Thank you @BLUEPIXY